# How to include extra jar dependency when running JMeter file with Java code?

Tags: java, jmeter

So I created a folder under 'resources' folder as JMeter home:

[image]

And I have the following code to run a JMX file:

```
// JMeter Engine
StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

// Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
File jmeterProperties = new ClassPathResource("/jmeter/JMeterHome/bin/jmeter.properties").getFile();
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getAbsolutePath());
File jmeterHome = new ClassPathResource("/jmeter/JMeterHome").getFile();
JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getAbsolutePath());
JMeterUtils.initLocale();

// Initialize JMeter SaveService
SaveService.loadProperties();

// Load existing .jmx Test Plan
File jmx = new ClassPathResource("/jmeter/some-test.jmx").getFile();
HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(jmx);

// Run JMeter Test
jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
jmeter.run();
```

However, I get ClassNotFoundException and that's because none of the jar files within lib folder are being loaded

```
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : com.tag.jmeter.ext.config.PropertyReader
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/com.tag.jmeter.ext.config.PropertyReader
```

The thing is a lot of these jar files are not even in maven repo and there are so many of them. What is the best way to include them in classpath or have I missed something here?

Temporarily I added the following dependency and it worked but this isn't the right solution:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>all</groupId>
    <artifactId>all</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jmeter/JMeterHome/lib/tag-jmeter-extn-1.1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Please note that, I am writing a series of util classes to run jmx files and this is going to be a shared util project that can be used in other projects as dependency to run their jmx files.

This is my pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-math3</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-pool2</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-math3</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-pool2</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_components</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-math3</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-pool2</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_config</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-math3</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-pool2</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

As you can see we are using JMeter v 2.13 and I can't upgrade because there are hundreds of jmx written with this version and upgrading is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is about missing [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) class implementation in order to be able to use it you need to add an `ApacheJMeter_jdbc` dependency like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

---

According to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) you should always be using the latest available JMeter version which is [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) for the moment so consider switching `<version>` of "JMeter" components to `4.0`

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong error message... I have edited my post and added more info. Sorry again